# xwindows working but not unity desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, x-windows, ubuntu-unity

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit w/ unity desktop

What I'm experiencing: When I turn on my computer, the Ubuntu loading screen appears but disappears in wake of a shell which I can log into.

Once logged in, I can start Unity via sudo start lightdm and subsequently login via unity gui.

However, the desktop software doesnt seem to be running. There is now tool-bar/menu-thing. I cannot use Alt+Tab to cycle between open windows, and I cannot restore windows which I minimize.

In every respect, I would have the same experience issuing sudo startx from an xterminal. I have reinstalled unity to no avail. installation seems to go just fine.

Any ideas on where I might go about addressing this problem? Thanks

linux ubuntu xwindows ubuntu-unity

Comment: Side note: it's mostly a bad idea to run startx as root, i.e. using `sudo startx`. Is there a specific reason you're doing this?

Comment: No, I noticed I couldnt start lightdm unless I was root, so I assumed the same was true with startx. In retrospect, I dont see why. Just out of curiosity though, what's bad about it?

Comment: In my (albeit limited) experience, it can really mess up permissions in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

If that doesn't work, try opening /etc/X11/default-display-manager in nano/whatever text editor you as root and replace whatever's in there with `usr/bin/lightdm` or "`usr/sbin/lightdm`. That should work after your reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's Compiz's problem.

1. Install CompizConfig by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and type `sudo apt-get install ccsm`
2. Press Alt+F2 and type ccsm
3. Go to the `Window Management` tab
4. Check `Application Switcher`, `Maximize`, `Move Window`, `Resize Window` and `Place Window`
5. Now go to the `Effects` tab
6. Tick the box `Window Decoration`
7. Go to `Preferences`
8. In the Backend section, choose `GSetting Configuration Backend`
9. Click `Back` and them `Close`
10. Press Alt+F2 and type `compiz --replace` (After you type, the screen may flicker a bit)
    urati
11. Go to the Dash, type `Startup Applications`
12. Click `Add` and type `compiz --replace` at the Command section, in the Name section, type whatever name you like

Voilà, you can now switch windows using Alt+Tab.